# SRTH instruction causing unaligned memory access fault on Cortex M7

Tags: arm, cortex-m

I have an IMXRT1060 and getting an unaligned access fault due to an STRH instruction. The odd thing is that the Cortex-M7 manual explicitly mentions that unaligned access are accepted for certain instructions, STRH being one of them.

`strh    r7, [r0, #4]`

Register values before that line:

[image]

Also, CCR has catching unaligned accesses disabled:

[image]

Comment: you enabled unaligned accesses or disabled the unaligned trap in the core whichever way the bit is documented?

Comment: I tried both options. My understanding of the documentation is that when bit 4 of that register is set to 0, then unaligned accesses don't generate a fault.

Comment: 0 Trapping disabled.  yeah, bit 3 a zero disables...did you read back the ccr to confirm you actually changed it?

Comment: Some peripheral busses don't allow this even if the core does.

Comment: good point what does the documentation for the part say (not arm, the chip vendor)?

Comment: There's no mention of unaligned accesses in NXP's documentation unfortunately. The company that we bought our OS from had similar issues with GCC (not with IAR) and think it's very likely that NXP didn't implement the unaligned access in the chip iitself

Yes, I did check the CCR register right before the instruction that causes the fault.